# jgroup GOOGLE_PING members not removed

Tags: infinispan

I am using GOOGLE_PING discovery protocol in Infinispan but it is not removing the non existing members from the cluster file (say abc.list) on storage. This is the version information:

Infinispan 8.x
Jgroups 3.7.x

Can you please help me with this issue?

Thanks,
Sanjiv

Comment: Have you tried with the most recent Infinispan release? `GOOGLE_PING` is not a very commonly used discovery protocol so this could be a bug (iow, you might need to debug the code to figure out what's up). If you're running Infinispan on OpenShift on Google Cloud there are other alternatives...

Comment: Thanks Galder. Its fixed after updating jroups to 4.x.

Comment: Awesome!! Please mark the question as resolved :)